# How to make SQL query to select unique id and range them in columns by date?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос, select

Помогите сделать SQL запрос на выборку id, отсортированных по дате от 01.01.2018 по 04.01.2018? В моей таблице login - тип varchar.

```
  users
id     login
-----------------
100  04.01.2018
101  01.01.2018
180  02.01.2018
103  03.01.2018
104  02.03.2018
205  03.01.2018
203  05.04.2018
```

Требуемое представление:

```
01.01.2018   02.01.2018   03.01.2018   04.01.2018  
    1           1            2             1
```

Я сделал такой запрос, но он не работает

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) as '01.01.2018' FROM users
where login = '01.01.2018'
union
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) as '02.01.2018' FROM users
where login = '02.01.2018';
union
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) as '03.01.2018' FROM users
where login = '03.01.2018';
union
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) as '06.04.2018' FROM users
where login = '04.01.2018';
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: ``SELECT SUM(login='2018-01-01')  `01.01.2018`, ...``

Comment: Спасибо! Такой код действительно заработал.
    

SELECT 
    SUM(first_login_time = '01.01.2018') `01.01.2018`,
    SUM(first_login_time = '02.01.2018') `02.01.2018`,
    SUM(first_login_time = '03.01.2018') `03.01.2018`,
    SUM(first_login_time = '04.01.2018') `04.01.2018` from users;


А есть ли способы еще больше упростить, например, указав интервал дат? Дело в том, что выборка может быть и за большое количество дней. Чтоб в ручную не писать каждую дату

Comment: Чтобы вручную не писать, стоит пользоваться `GROUP BY`.  `SELECT COUNT(*), login FROM users GROUP BY(login)`. Получите другой вид, но не будете страдать ерундой

Comment: *А есть ли способы еще больше упростить, например, указав интервал дат?* Упростить - нет. Это однозначно усложнит код. MySQL не знает про PIVOT (уж больно оно нереляционное), но да, формально можно, написав соотв. хранимую процедуру. Хотя правильнее выполнить трансформацию уже на клиенте средствами компонента построения отчётов.